# Excel, trying to split rent for the number of days in a month, per month for the whole year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I am trying to calculate rent for each month. The problem I am facing is with the fact that starting date and ending date could be in the middle of a month.

For example:

```
Rent = 10,000
Starting date = 15/04/2020
Ending date = 10/10/2020
```

I want my excel Sheet to split accordingly as below:
[First sample row of the excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWy79.png)

In my excel sheet, I have different amounts for rent and various start/end dates.
This is what I have tried but failed miserably:

```
> =$F3/(12*DAY(EOMONTH(H$1,0)))*(IF(MONTH($C3)<=MONTH(H$1),IF(MONTH($C3)=MONTH(H$1),(EOMONTH($D3,0)-$D3),DAY(EOMONTH(H$1,0))),0))
```

Where F is where the RENT is, H1 is January, C3 is start date, D3 is end date. I'm hoping it to work when I autofill the formula across the whole sheet.

Please help!

@Hooded0ne I tried your formula for all examples in my sheet and there seems to be an issue for some cases:

1. [When start date is 2019 and end date is 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB2R8.png). This should only show rent till April.
2. [Same case as above, December 2020 is only till the 14th, it should only calculate for the first 15 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY9Nf.png)

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

`=MAX((MIN(EOMONTH(K1,0),$D$3)-MAX(K1,$C$3)+1)/DAY(EOMONTH(K1,0))/12*$F$3,0)`

[image]

Edit: It should work for multiple years, if you have a specific example, please add it to your original post.

Comment: Issue here: doesn't work for other cases as mentioned in my question

Comment: Hi,  I have added a screenshot of how my formula works with the two additional examples you provided. Please let me know if these are not the results you desire.